# Convert from QASM code to Qiskit Code

Tags: qiskit, qasm

I'm looking for something that performs a conversion such as `qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.qasm`, but for qasm code. In other words, a means to convert qasm code to qiskit code?

Not just converting from qasm code to a `QuantumCircuit` object, but yielding the actual qiskit code. The closest method I've found is to paste the qasm code into IBM's circuit composer then copying from there. However, I need to automate the process.
Does anyone know about an existing function like this or do I need to write it myself?

Thanks in advance, and I'm new to this site so hopefully I haven't broken any rules! If I have, please let me know.

Comment: You might want to check out this StackOverflow answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29586/is-there-any-method-to-parse-a-qasm-in-qiskit

Comment: Thanks for the link @FrankYellin, seems related yes.

Comment: tbh you could try gpt4 with an API key. Might not get it perfect but will come pretty close

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across a website called the 'Quantum Programming Studio' which seems to serve this purpose: https://quantum-circuit.com/qconvert

[image: Quantum Programming Studio]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [`QuantumCircuit`'s method `from_qasm_str`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str.html) takes an OpenQASM 2 definition of a circuit and converts it into a `QuantumCircuit` Qiskit object:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circuit = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str("""
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[2];
cz q[0],q[1];
u(2*pi,3*pi,-5*pi) q[0];
""")
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: Quantum circuit]

If the OpenQASM code is in a file, you can use [`QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file('filename.qasm')`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @luciano. However, I'm looking for a method that converts qasm code into qiskit code such that it can be automated. Not a QuantumCircuit object. But perhaps there is a way to convert a QuantumCircuit object into qiskit code? I'm not sure yet.

Comment: there is now way to do that at the moment. What's the use case for it?

Comment: For example using a benchmark set of quantum programs written in qasm, but you want to automatically load them into another backend that reads qiskit code. So just practical things like that. @luciano

Comment: Backends consume Qiskit `QuantumCircuit` objects. You can do that loading a QASM and send it to run.

Comment: For the benchmarks, it may make sense to start from something framework-independent and generate framework-specific circuits from there.